# how to give give multiple expressions to a identifier in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

Hey I'm trying to make a multiple divergence indicator. When I tried to define "osc =" with "cci" and "mfi" both together compiler was giving error.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Divergence Indicator", formatt=format.price)

showcci = input(true)
showmfi = input(true)

lbR = input(title="Pivot Lookback Right", defval=5)
lbL = input(title="Pivot Lookback Left", defval=5)
rangeUpper = input(title="Max of Lookback Range", defvall=60)
rangeLower = input(title="Min of Lookback Range", defval=5)
plotBull = input(title="Plot Bullish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title="Plot Hidden Bullish", defval=false)
plotBear = input(title="Plot Bearish", defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title="Plot Hidden Bearish", defval=false)

bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.new(color.green, 80)
hiddenBearColor = color.new(color.red, 80)
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)


//cci
cci= cci(close, 14)
plot(showcci ? cci : na, color=color.blue, title="CCI")

//mfi
mfi= mfi(hlc3, 14)
plot(showmfi ? mfi : na, color=color.yellow, title="MFI")
```

The error begins here...
I know that variable can contains only one value but is their any way to make both indicators divergence appears at same time?

```
osc = cci, mfi


plFound = na(pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
bars = barssince(cond == true)
rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

oscHL = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)


bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

 plot(
 plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Regular Bullish",
 linewidth=2,
 color=(bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor),
 transp=0
 )

 plotshape(
 bullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Regular Bullish Label",
 text=" B ",
 style=shape.labelup,
 location=location.absolute,
 color=noneColor,
 textcolor=bullColor,
 transp=0
 )

oscLL = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

priceHL = low[lbR] > valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

 plot(
 plFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Hidden Bullish",
 linewidth=2,
 color=(hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor),
 transp=0
 )

 plotshape(
 hiddenBullCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Hidden Bullish Label",
 text=" HB ",
 style=shape.labelup,
 location=location.absolute,
 color=noneColor,
 textcolor=bullColor,
 transp=0
 )

oscLH = osc[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

priceHH = high[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

 plot(
 phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Regular Bearish",
 linewidth=2,
 color=(bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor),
 transp=0
 )

 plotshape(
 bearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Regular Bearish Label",
 text=" S ",
 style=shape.labeldown,
 location=location.absolute,
 color=noneColor,
 textcolor=bearColor,
 transp=0
 )

oscHH = osc[lbR] > valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

priceLH = high[lbR] < valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

 plot(
 phFound ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Hidden Bearish",
 linewidth=2,
 color=(hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor),
 transp=0
 )

 plotshape(
 hiddenBearCond ? osc[lbR] : na,
 offset=-lbR,
 title="Hidden Bearish Label",
 text=" HB ",
 style=shape.labeldown,
 location=location.absolute,
 color=noneColor,
 textcolor=bearColor,
 transp=0
 )
alertcondition(condition = (bullCond or hiddenBullCond), title = "Bullish Divergence", message = "Bullish Divergence")
alertcondition(condition = (bearCond or hiddenBearCond), title = "Bearish Divergence", message = "Bearish Divergence")
```

I'm rookie btw :>

Comment: You should post the entire script that's producing the error. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for guidance I'll edit my question... I tried to upload image before but it didn't allowed me ._.

Answer (score 0):

You may use tuples for that:

```
ccimfi() =>
    [cci(close, 14) , mfi(hlc3, 14)] 
    
[cci, mfi] = ccimfi()

plot(showcci ? cci : na, color=color.blue, title="CCI")
plot(showmfi ? mfi : na, color=color.yellow, title="MFI")
```

and so on.

https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Declaring_functions.html?highlight=tuple#id5

Comment: I tried this but didn't worked "osc" identifier necessary for below divergence plots

Comment: I used "?" opretor it's working but it showing divergence on only one indicator, like if i enable rsi and mfi at same time script showing divergence on rsi only